# Joomla Framework Questions

Tags: php, joomla, themes

I'm planning to make me a new website. I have choosen Joomla as my CMS to go.
But before I start, I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible (and easy) to change the Theme on the fly? So that a user can select an alternate theme?
2. What do u think about frameworks? Especially for Joomla. Should i use one? If yes, which one do you suggest? (a free one)

Comment: By the way, I wouldn't call Joomla a framework. And to answer your second question, the answer is always the same: it depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I know, Joomla is a CMS. But there are frameworks specially for joomla.

Comment: Actually Joomla! these days is two products Joomla! CMS which sits on top of Joomla! Platform. The platform allows different apps to be built on top of it like cli apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes it is possible for the user to switch the template on the fly. See [this extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/templating/7466).
2. Joomla! has its own built in [MVC framework](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5) which you'll see and use if you develop your own components. There is no need to use another framework within that.